# Как происходит расчет стоимости использования DocumentDB?

Tags: база-данных, nosql, azure

Как происходит расчет стоимости использования NoSQL базы данных DocumentDB в Microsoft Azure? В калькуляторе расчета стоимости есть поле "количество коллекций", на которое, собственно, и умножается итоговая стоимость. + как я понял, в тарифах указаны цены за 10Гб (2 руб/час). Так вот, если у меня будут, скажем, не одна коллекция на 10Гб, а штук 50 коллекций по 200мб, каков будет итоговый чек? 2 руб\час или с учетом кол-ва коллекций: 100руб\час?
И еще вопрос: если я занимаю, скажем, не 10Гб, а 1Гб, влияет ли это на конечную стоимость услуг или они округляют в большую сторону?
Интересуют ответы тех, кто уже пользовался этим сервисом.

Comment: Эти вопросы не технического характера. Не имеют прямого отношения к программированию или системному администрированию. Их стоит направить в тех. поддержку Azure.

Comment: Хоть и вопрос не относится к программированию на прямую, но данная тема часто встречается в практике использования сервисами Azure и в итоге с программиста и спросят "сколько это будет примерно нам стоить".